# jQuery not appending some elements while creating them

Tags: jquery

I would like to ask if anybody sees what is going on. I have plenty experience with jQuery append elements while creating them, I made this several times but now Im struggling since 2 hours without being able to find my mistake, perhaps you can help me.

I'm trying to append the following as stated below:

```
var contactoHolder = $('<div />', {'class':"contactoUnexpanded",'id':indexed});
contactoHolder.append(infoArray[0]);
$('<div />', {'class':"editDelete", 'id':indexed+'editDelete'}).appendTo(contactoHolder);     
$('<span />', {'class':"edit",'id':indexed+'_edit'}).appendTo('#'+indexed+'editDelete');
$('#'+indexed+'_edit').html('edit');
$('<span />', {'class':"delete",'id':indexed+'_delete'}).appendTo('#' + indexed + 'editDelete');
$('#' + indexed + 'delete').html('delete');
$('<span />', {'class':"contenidoDelContacto", 'id':indexed + 'Content'}).appendTo(contactoHolder);
$('#' + indexed + 'Content').html('<br />' + infoArray[1] + '<br />' + infoArray[2] + '<br />' + infoArray[3] + '<br />' + infoArray[4]);
$('#content').append(contactoHolder);
```

The only elementswhen I render that get definitively in the DOM are

```
<div id="19" class="contactoUnexpanded contactoExpanded">
  Santiago
  <div id="19editDelete" class="editDelete"></div>
  <span id="19Content" class="contenidoDelContacto"></span>
</div>
```

I don't know why is not appending the rest of the elements as it should.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Mind posting a fiddle? What does `infoArray` contain? Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: no console error. infoArray is ["Santiago", "av del parque", "099625635", "6826910", "san@gmail.com"] as example

Comment: I expect that the word 'edit' gets into the $('#'+indexed+'_edit') element created above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems start here:

```
$('<span />', {'class':"delete",'id':indexed+'_delete'}).appendTo('#' + indexed + 'editDelete');
```

Since you haven't appended any of your elements to the DOM yet, `('#' + indexed + 'editDelete')` doesn't match anything. The selector engine only looks at elements currently in the DOM, not those in JavaScript variables.

You can solve this by appending the `contactoHolder` right away: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ptpgJ/

```
var contactoHolder = $('<div />', {'class':"contactoUnexpanded",'id':indexed});
$('#content').append(contactoHolder); 
// now the rest of your code
```

---

Alternatively, try assigning each new jQuery element a variable name, and reference those variables instead when appending or modifying them. This should be more efficient, but the difference will probably be imperceptible to your users unless you're doing this hundreds or thousands of times in a row:

```
var div1 = $('<div />', {'class':"editDelete", 'id':indexed+'editDelete'}).appendTo(contactoHolder);     
// ...
$('<span />', {'class':"delete",'id':indexed+'_delete'}).appendTo(div1);
```

All together: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/B33wW/

```
var contactoHolder = $('<div />', {
    'class': "contactoUnexpanded",
    'id': indexed
});
contactoHolder.append(infoArray[0]);
var div1 = $('<div />', {
    'class': "editDelete",
    'id': indexed + 'editDelete'
}).appendTo(contactoHolder);

var span1 = $('<span />', {
    'class': "edit",
    'id': indexed + '_edit'
}).appendTo(div1);
$(span1).html('edit');

var span2 = $('<span />', {
    'class': "delete",
    'id': indexed + '_delete'
}).appendTo(div1);
$(span2).html('delete');

var span3 = $('<span />', {
    'class': "contenidoDelContacto",
    'id': indexed + 'Content'
}).appendTo(contactoHolder);
$(span3).html('<br />' + infoArray[1] + '<br />' + infoArray[2] + '<br />' + infoArray[3] + '<br />' + infoArray[4]);
$('#content').append(contactoHolder);
```

Comment: amazing answer, what I needed to know and explained clearly, didnt realize about as I used to append each one at the time and now Im doing it only once kinda backbone el. thank you very much